Isolating $z$ in the equation $x - 1 = - \frac{1-y^{z+1}-0.5(1-y^z)}{(1-y)y^z}$
I have a formula with multiple unknowns:
$$x - 1 = - \frac{1-y^{z+1}-0.5(1-y^z)}{(1-y)y^z}$$
The way it is setup now allows to easily calculate $x$, but I would like to reformulate it to isolate $z$, such that in the end I have $z = ...$
I tried multiple times, including with logs, but without success.

Put $w=y^z$ and solve for w in terms of x and y.

@Paul I tried like this but I end up with w in terms of x, y, and w. I cannot get rid of the remaing w

Try again, you are doing something wrong algebraically $x - 1 = - \frac{1-wy-0.5(1-w)}{(1-y)w}$

Multiplying by $-(1-y)y^z$, we get
$$
-(x-1)(1-y)y^z = 1- y\cdot y^z - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}
y^z$$
Then move the $y^z$-terms to the left-hand-side
$$
-(x-1)(1-y)y^z + (y-\frac{1}{2})y^z = \frac{1}{2}
$$
Group the terms to get
$$
\left[y - \frac{1}{2} - (x-1)(1-y)
\right]y^z = \frac{1}{2}
$$
A slight simplification and division ...
$$y^z = \frac{1}{2x(y-1)+1}$$
Finally, taking the logarithm leads to
$$
z = \frac{ \ln \left(\frac{1}{2x(y-1)+1} \right) }{\ln y}= - \frac{ \ln \left(2x(y-1)+1 \right)}{\ln y} 
$$

Yes, I obtained in the end $z = -\frac{ln[\frac{1}{2} + x(y - 1)]}{ln[y]}$, is that correct?
